# Error in Visual Studio 2019 when opening the Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics because of the following error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands' or one of its dependencies. The specified file cannot be found. Please help me solve this problem.[Package Manager Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaElW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the limitation, I post this as an answer, but may include some comments.(Sorry for that)

Anyways, may I ask, which NuGet package did you install and use? Did you follow some documents or guidance to configure or do something? Could you tell me what operations you performed? If it is possible, could you provide me with some steps to reproduce this error/issue?

**Some suggestions:**

1). Please check the dependencies list of the related NuGet packages which you installed on nuget.org to see whether some requirements(dependencies) are needed.

2). Maybe you need to check whether you have installed the correct version of NuGet package.

3). Perhaps, one certain NuGet package is missing(wasn’t installed).

4). Please kindly try to remove the NuGet packages and then reinstall them again.

5). Please try to close VS and then restart VS, `clean` and `rebuild` your project.

Comment: The Package Manager console shows this error in any project, even where there are no Nuget packages. I reinstalled Visual Studio, it didn't help either.

Comment: Have you also tried to `Clear All NuGet Cache(s)`? From VS > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General > select `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` and `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio` and then click `Clear All NuGet Cache(s)` option and then check if it works.